# Query to distribute value from one table to another by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

`table A` will have one food from  `table B` b

```
Table A
Name      | Value  | Food
-----------------------------
Ahmed     | 1      | 
Ali       | 83     | 
Peter     | 19     | 
Sam       | 8      | 
Sara      | 9      | 
Loyel     | 101    | 

Table B
FoodName  | Remaining
-------------------
Apple     | 3   
Mango     | 2




 Table A
Name      | Value  | Food
-----------------------------
Ahmed     | 1      | Apple
Ali       | 83     | Apple
Peter     | 19     | Apple
Sam       | 8      | Mango
Sara      | 9      | Mango
Loyel     | 101    | Null
```

Whats the set base query, where as I want to avoid loop, or recursive function that what I had implemented?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2017

Comment: How come Loyel doesn't get any fruit?

Comment: @gvee it all runs out before they get to Loyel (5 pieces of fruit, 6 names).

Comment: @QuaperClient is there a way of ordering tableA e.g. an `id` field? Otherwise there can be no guarantee as to what order the rows are selected from that table.

Comment: @gvee all fruits has been finished before her

Comment: @Nick there is an identity column ID

Comment: @QuaperClient great. We can all modify our answers to order by that so as to give consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is hackish way to do this, using window functions, in particular `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cteB AS (
    SELECT FoodName, Remaining,
        COALESCE(SUM(Remaining) OVER (ORDER BY FoodName ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND PRECEDING ROW), 0) AS RemainingStart,
        SUM(Remaining) OVER (ORDER BY FoodName) RemainingEnd
    FROM TableB
),
cteA AS (
    SELECT Name, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) rn
    FROM TableA
)

SELECT
    a.Name,
    a.Value,
    b.FoodName AS Food
FROM cteA a
LEFT JOIN cteB b
    ON a.rn > b.RemainingStart AND a.rn <= b.RemainingEnd;
```

[image]

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=573e04141edfb3b8fe64a550a3393057)

The idea behind the logic I used was to generate, using window functions, a pseudo-food order for each item in the B table, numbered from 0 going as high as the total count of food items.  Then, also assign a row number to each person in the A table, and then match up person to food item using this pseudo sequence.

Note that my answer falls short in the case where we might want to iterate more than once and assign multiple to food items to each person.

Comment: @Nick I just learned that window frame syntax depends on the language locale being used in SQL Server.  On European machines, it is `PRECEDING 1`, while on American ones it is `1 PRECEDING`.  This is why my first attempt did not run.

Comment: How bizarre! What happens if you have a team that's on both continents?

Comment: Yeah, that's a really good question.  [Read this Italian SQL Server blog post](https://afercondini.wordpress.com/2016/01/02/soma-parcial-over/) if you don't believe me :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to know , why are you using BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND PRECEDING ROW. Because it equals with just sum over partition

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar The thing is, I need to take the sum over all previous records _except_ for the current record in the frame.  For example, for mango I want its range to go from the sum of (3) to (3+2), that is, run from 3 to 5, to cover those 2 users who would be assigned mangos.  Just taking the sum will over count by one record.

Answer (score 2):

You need no loop.

```
select a.Name, a.Value, b.FoodName
from
  (select *, row_number() over(order by Name) rn
   from tabeA) a
left join
  (select *, sum(Remaining) over(order by FoodName) running_total
   from tableB) b on a.rn between b.running_total - b.Remaining + 1 and b.running_total;
```

If you need another ordering for `TableA`, change  `row_number() over(order by Name)` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using a recursive CTE to generate a table with rows for each of the remaining fruit. This must then be joined to tableA by row_number, with tableA's row_number effectively randomly generated:

```
with cte as (
select FoodName, Remaining from tableB
union all
select FoodName, Remaining - 1 from cte
where Remaining - 1 > 0)
select a.Name, a.[value], c.FoodName
from (select *,
             row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as rn
      from tableA) a
left join (select *, 
                  row_number() over (order by FoodName, Remaining) as rn
           from cte) c on c.rn = a.rn
```

Output:

```
Name    value   FoodName
Ahmed   1       Apple
Ali     83      Apple
Peter   19      Apple
Sam     8       Mango
Sara    9       Mango
Loyel   101
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b1af99a14c5ea145344b46315d263af3)

**Update**

Since there is an `id` identity column, we can order by that instead. Change `(order by (select 1))` to `(order by id)` in the query.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ba5c543cbb843a1e9c13d3528196abfc)

Comment: `row_number() over (order by (select 1))` does not guarantee any order. In many cases it will be the order the rows where inserted, but some day it will not.

Comment: @Serg you are correct, so I have asked the question in the comments.

Comment: @Serg you'll notice that I had written that tableA's row_number was effectively random in the answer.

Comment: @Serg The OP itself does not really give any well defined order, so Nick's assumption is reasonable.